# Yajra Laravel Datatables display key value pair table

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm new to Laravel and I'm having a hard time on displaying the table with key-value pair structure. Here's my table structure

[image]

Comment: That table doesn't make much sense. `firstname`, `lastname`, `age` and `birthdate` should be columns, not rows. That being said, what have you tried to solve this? Posting an image of a table with no code associated is not acceptable for Stackoverflow. You need to show your attempts and as much data as is necessary for us to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table structure buddy,

Firstname, lastname, age are columns not rows.
id primary key|| Foreign key||firstname||lastname||age||birthday
1              || 1         || John     ||Doe    ||21  || 02/02/19917